# Why water doesn't drop down from a hole when a stream of water travels fast over it?

Tags: surface-tension, bernoulli-equation

why water doesn't fall down from hole on the roof when its raining heavily (water moves fast  on the roof) ? Can I know the theory behind this and the factors affecting?

Comment: Maybe the Venturi effect? https://www.wassertec.co.za/wp-content/uploads/venturis-mazzei-768x235.jpg

Comment: What kind of hole size and what sort of roof slope are you talking about?

Comment: yeah it seems the Venturi effect and Bernuli effects have a connection to this ! I am in need of building a mathematical model to determine the flow rate of the liquid where the liquid will not drop down from the hole. So Im looking for the parameters affecting this phenomenon. Thanks guys :)